# How do I run Lua script using Arduino IDE ? (Using an Arduino uno board as the serial provider for ESP8266)

Tags: lua, arduino, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

(I am a complete newbie to microcontrollers and I am a barely intermediate level programmer)

If I send these commands through the serial monitor everything works fine . But if I try it using the code below it just does't work and show errors and what not.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 4); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
    // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

    // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.println("conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)");
    mySerial.println("conn:on('receive', function(conn, payload) print(payload) end)"); 
    mySerial.println("conn:connect(80,'50.87.151.128')");
    mySerial.println("conn:send('GET /devashishproject/time.php HTTP/1.1\\r\\n')");
    mySerial.println("conn:send('Host: kartikkhattar.com\\r\\n')");
    mySerial.println("conn:send('Accept: */*\\r\\n')"); 
    mySerial.println("conn:send('User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)\\r\\n')");
    mySerial.println("conn:send('\\r\\n')");
}
void loop() // run over and over
{
    if (mySerial.available())
        Serial.print((char)mySerial.read());
    if (Serial.available())
        mySerial.write((char)Serial.read());
}
```

It just shows garbled information .Where am I going wrong? Does it have to do the power supply? But it works normally when enter these commands through the serial monitor? Why won't it work when I put it in a code like above?

Comment: Sorry, but... That code uses the hardware serial to communicate.. If you attached the ESP on other pins than 0 and 1 you should use the SoftwareSerial library as in the lines you commented out. If, on the other hand, you are using the hardware serial this should work. You can still see the sent commands because they are on the same line as the serial adapter, but you won't see the answers (they are on the wrong line). Anyway, it should work.

Comment: Yes the ESP pins are connected to the 0th and 1st pins on the board. I just cant seem to get it to work . I want to be able to see whatever responses its getting on the serial monitor.

Comment: I wonder if I am messing up the quotation marks .

Comment: @DevashishKhattar you should escape the quotation marks inside your strings, C-like languages will concatenate the strings together so "this""that" is the same as "thisthat". Since you are printing Lua code though, using single quotes inside the string for Lua strings will work without ugly escapes.

Comment: I just updated the code in my question and that is what I have been trying to run . I have not been able to make it work even using the SoftwareSerial.h library(using pins 2 and 4 as software serial) and even by replacing double quotes with single ones. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You'll still need to escape \r and \n as \\r and \\n

Comment: I still get this as the result on the serial monitor after making those changes.

Goodnight moon!
r•õå«W%,KP@¥i½z:�Uk+ë¢¬E\Xloa¥ÁÉ‚‘*ù‘¥¤õËËÓ¬X]œ–'5\ÝŠªr”HhËtible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n')
conn:send('\r\n')
stdin:1: '=' expected near ';'
>